# Separate Value in R (Table)

Tags: r, tidyr

I have one table consisting of location value (long lat) such as below:

[image]

How to code in R for separating this long and lat value
I have used func separate but return to error (it is chr datatype). But when I change it to Num and Int, it returns NA.

Thank you for your help

```
separate(df, col=Vehicle.Location, into=c('long', 'lat'), sep='-')
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Please do not post an image of code/data/errors [for these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Just include the code and data directly, e.g. to share a snippet of your data run `dput(head(ev))` and copy the result into your post.

Comment: Also, have a look at [Converting Geometry to Longitude/Latitude coordinates in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47661354/converting-geometry-to-longitude-latitude-coordinates-in-r)

Answer (score 2):

Your character column is a so-called well-known text (WKT) representation of point coordinates. You can either leave it as text and extract the components from there or convert it into a proper spatial object like so:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.11.0, GDAL 3.5.3, PROJ 9.1.0; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

df <- tribble(
  ~DOL.Vehicle.ID, ~Vehicle.Location,
  249675142, "POINT (-122.34301 47.659185)"
)

# convert WKT representation to geometry and extract coordinates
st_coordinates(st_as_sfc(df$Vehicle.Location))
#>             X        Y
#> [1,] -122.343 47.65919

# extract from text
df |> 
  separate_wider_delim(
    Vehicle.Location,
    delim = " ",
    names = c("point", "long", "lat")
  ) |> 
  mutate(across(c(long, lat), parse_number)) |> 
  select(!point)
#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>   DOL.Vehicle.ID  long   lat
#>            <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1      249675142 -122.  47.7
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you but when I extract it from text, it returns ! object 'parse_number' not found

Comment: `parse_number()` is a function from the readr package. It is automatically loaded when you run the first line `library(tidyverse)`.

Answer (score 0):

A solution inspired by dufei but using only the tidyr library.
After putting the table into `ev` run

```r
ev <- separate_wider_delim(ev, Vehicle.Location,delim=" ",names=c("point","long","lat"))

ev <- ev[,-2] # remove the 'point' column

ev$long <- substring(ev$long,2)
ev$lat <- substring(ev$lat,1,nchar(ev$lat)-1)

ev

## A tibble: 3 × 3
#  DOL.Vehicle.ID long         lat       
#           <dbl> <chr>        <chr>     
#1      249675142 -122.34301   47.659185 
#2      233928502 -122.20578   47.762405 
#3      229675939 -120.6027202 46.5965625
```

If the data type must be numeric then also run this:

```r
ev$long <- as.numeric(ev$long)
ev$lat <- as.numeric(ev$lat)
```